# app.config: ConnectionString value not visible in project where it's defined

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Hi I have a few projects in Solution.
In project A, I have app.config with connection string called Ver3ConnectionString. But when I do debug, the connection string is not found in code:). While debugging connection strings contains one which is not defined in this app.config, nether in my app :). Im using VS2013 Express :).

Moreover, applicationSettings are ones which are defined in main project:), but not one which is being dubugged.

Magic:).

ADDED:

1. THe solution was created by my coworker from existing project, so Im looking for error in solution/project files.
2. MobileWalletContext class is connected with EntityFramework 6.X. Maybe this is the problem?

Added 2:
This unknown connection string has **name ="LocalSqlServer"**. Maybe this will be helpful?

App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>    
   <add name="Ver3ConnectionString"
      connectionString="Data Source=PAZI-PRO2\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MobileWalletVer3;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

C# code where connsterionString is called:

```
public MobileWalletContext() : base(string.Format("name={0}",ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Ver3ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {          

            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MobileWalletContext>()); 
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Name of the connection string is not likely to change. Therefore I would simplify context constructor to:

```
public MobileWalletContext() : base("Ver3ConnectionString")
{          
    Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MobileWalletContext>()); 
}
```

That way I could define different connection string in each project using `Ver3ConnectionString` name.

**EDIT**

`DbContext` base constructor accepts both connection string name or full connection string.

In your case instead of referencing existing connection string you are just creating a new connection string with provided name and default settings. Thats why you are seeing LocalSqlServer.

If you pass name of existing connection string in config, it will be picked up and used.

**EDIT**

Make sure your connection strings are in `app.config` or `web.config` file in your main project directory.

Comment: I understand the change , but I want to undestand it fully:).

Comment: Edited my answer to add some details

Comment: I changed base constructor call to: base("name=XXX") where XXX is defined connection string name, but I have error: No connection string named 'XXX' could be found in the application config file. Magic again :)

Comment: You don't need "name=" part. Just set it to the name of connection string only. Like this:  `base("XXX")`

Comment: I deleted this "name" part. It created new database, but now it seems not to use connection string. How it works:) How it 's gonna behave on production server:)

Comment: What do you mean by that? If it created database, then it is using connection string.

Comment: No, my code is base("Ver3_1") and I have such new db, but I dont have it defined in ap.config. This maybe be some EF convention:)

Comment: I found a solution, I had to add Connection String entry to main project (web api 2). The project where it was orginally was dll project, which cannot contain app.config :).

Comment: I wanted to suggest you the same thing but in you question you said that  **Moreover, applicationSettings are ones which are defined in main project ** so I assumed that this is not the case. I updated my answer, to include this so you can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add this to what @Kaspars-Ozols wrote:
LocalSqlServer is your SQL Express installation and its configuration usually resides in a machine.config file like `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config`. You may have more than 1 machine.config `[2 runtimes (2.0 and 4.0)]` x `[2 Bitness (x86 and x64)]` makes 4 machine.config files!

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

**It's a good habit to use `<clear />` at the very beginning of `<appSettings>` or `<connectionStrings>` sections.**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear/>
    <add name="MembershipConnection" connectionString="Server=.;UId=some_user;PWd=P@$$w0rd;Database=DBName" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="ElmahConnection" connectionString="Server=.;UId=some_elmah_user;PWd=P@$$w0rd;Database=DBName" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```